# How Can I Manipulate Some/IP Message Content On Run Time?

Tags: ethernet, capl, canoe

I was trying to manipulate SOME/IP messages by falsifying their content(Payload) sent between 2 ECUs at run time.

After setting up the Hardware VN6510A **MAC Bypassing** and integrating it in the data traffic path between those 2 ECUs to monitor and control all Ethernet data streams.

**ECU A** ---> *eth1 interface* --**VN6510A**-- *eth2 interface* ---> **ECU B**

I successfully catch our target SOME/IP messages and I also succefully manipulate their paylod.
But at the end we got 2 SOME/IP messages: the real coming message and the falsified message forwarded at the same time.

How could we bound those 2 SOME/IP messages, the real message and the falsified message together, so that we could have just one falsified SOME/IP message, knowing that I am using the same SOME/IP message handle.

I used the callback function **void OnEthPacket(LONG channel, LONG dir, LONG packet)** to register a received Ethernet packet.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by setting your VN.... to "Direct" and not "MAC Bypassing"

Answer (score 0):

Well we could not manipulate Messages at run time using the vector box VN6510A Solution because simply their box doesn't support this feature.